# Is there a way I can put some delay in setcontentView in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a SetContentView(R.layout.camera);
I want this layout to be start executing after some milliseconds....till then it should be blank. How can I achieve this in android?

Comment: Use SplashScreen with blank image & then start your Activity.

Comment: Please provide some context; both of code and of the software. Why do you want to do this? The right answer requires that one understands your requirements.

Comment: You should reconsider your requirements. Showing a blank screen to your users is a horrible UX concept ...

Comment: Not a good idea. Why do you want to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2):

For this Write your `onCreate()` like this..Then it will work..

```
Thread t = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                t.sleep(5000);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    }
                });

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    t.start();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use handler for make delay

```
 Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
       //setcontentview
    }
};
```

in oncreate methode

```
Message m = Message.obtainMessage();
handler.sendMessageDelayed(m, delayMillis);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your activity will not be visible unless **onResume()** will get called, Do some operation in main Thread or **onCreate()** Method  it will block your main thread and UI will not be displayed until your operation gets completed.

Answer (score 0):

Create root View with all the components and visibility set to **INVISIBLE** or **GONE** and then show it after delay. You can use Handler and postDelayed to execute a code after delay.